# How to animate rigidbody objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game in which I need to move an object straight up, and when it hits another object they are connected with joint. That's why I need to have rigidbodies attached to both of them. The problem is that when I use animation to do this, collision is not detected, and unity tends to crash. Is there any proper way of "animating" rigidbody objects? Or maybe I should choose a different approach?

Comment: What does rigid body sound like? Yes a different object type would not the non hackish preferred way. Can even have two objects. One rigid, and use the other one when you need it to move.

Comment: It's very true that an absolutely basic technique in vid games is **swapping between different versions of objects**.  This comes up all the time; most new hobbyist developers don't realize this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [`Rigidbody.isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) to `true` on the rigid bodies just *before* animating them. This will allow you to move (animate) the rigid bodies by changing the `transform.position` and other properties while allowing collisions with other non-kinematic bodies(rigid bodies with `isKinematic` set to `false`) and joint constraints to work properly. When the animation has completed and you want the bodies to be affected by physics again, set [`isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) to `false`.

Refer to [the documentation for `isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) for more information and a ragdoll example.